# Selected CollectionView cell appearance in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm building iOS app with swift. In my app I have ViewController with CollectionView in it. Everything is great, but when I click on cell Labels in it are automatically changing their color to black (and backgrounds if they are set to default).

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnO29.jpg)

When I use TableView I'm just selecting "Selection -> None" in Attributes inspector for the prototype cell and it helps, but cell in CollectionView doesn't have this option.

P.S. I don't want to customize it, I just want to disable changing UI when it's selected.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: There is no selectionStyle method in CollectionViewCell. You have to customize the changing ui.

Answer (score 0):

Set userInteraction of your label to false and then try to click on it.This will not change you UI. Remove the delegate from your collection view , to identify the issue in detail.